# How do I get these if statements to play nicely in c#

Tags: c#

I've modified my code to the point where it will execute, but it's linked to a timer, and will attempt to execute over and over till the timed condition is lost. I tried putting a "lock" on the system with a variable I named "intLimiter", to force the sequence to stop after one execution, but the lock doesn't seem to be working.

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == intAlarmHour && DateTime.Now.Minute == intAlarmMinute)
{
    if (intLimiter == 1)                    
    {
        intLimiter = 2;
        if (radTG.Checked)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Celldweller___Tough_Guy);
            sound.Play();                       
        }
               ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well from what I see you're checking the hour & minutes, so if it's in some kind of timer or loop it will be called multiple times for a full minute. You might want to add a flag to trigger it only once.

Comment: There's hardly anything one can make out of this. Very unclear. One suggestion, did you try `DateTime.Now.Hour >= intAlarmHour && DateTime.Now.Minute >= intAlarmMinute` ? May be something is not synchronized enough to check for an exact `==`

Comment: Some suggestions: dont use `radTG.Checked == true`. Just `radTG.Checked` is enough. Also, `intAlarmHour` is bad naming. Try `alarmHour`.

Comment: I noticed that nawfal had edited my original post, changing the code. I tried the altered code, and it works, but with the caveat that the program becomes non-responsive for the duration of whatever song plays. Which is fine for personal use, because I mean, those are all great songs to wake up to, but I doubt my professor would find it acceptable. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: @AarronDixon I did not *change* the code as in it's intent. I only shortened it. Btw, its too long to answer as answer here, but you should try to play the song in a background thread or so, to make the thread responsive. Search for *backgroundworker*. there are plenty of examples on SO. Or try the other `Play` overloads of the sound player.

Comment: Use Play instead of PlaySync. If you use the same thread (with PlaySync) it will indeed become non-responsive.

Comment: I tried changing to Play. It seems to give the first note of the song, then stop, then a second later try again. Like it's activating every time the timer goes off. The program does remain responsive though. How do you issue the flag to make it only trigger once? That might fix it.

Comment: @AarronDixon post a complete but short code, especially the timer part. Only then a suggestion can be given.

Comment: I'm a worthless newbie. I have no idea what could potentially be important and what's pointless. And the timer section includes probably 500 lines worth of code so far. I started at noon yesterday and got hooked. Considering pulling an all nighter. It's not that it's due soon, I'm just really enjoying struggling through code that's over my head! It ends up activating over and over for a minute now, I think if I could do that " You might want to add a flag to trigger it only once. " thing that was mentioned I could get it purring.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Clumsily, but it seems to work. I just added another "if" statement on a higher level than the actual song activation, that required a variable to be set at "1" in order to continue, and at the end of the music activation changed to "2". The Set Alarm button changes it back to "1". So it'll go off once then stop. Probably a terrible way to do it but it got the job done!

Comment: Eh nevermind, it works sometimes and not others. I've tried different variations, but it still seems to stutter and skip most of the time. I'm baffled, I even tried adding a change to the value of the "lock" to 2 with every song execution, just throw it around wildly, and still it tries to execute with the requirement of the "lock" being 1 over and over. I really don't know how it's getting past.

Comment: What is this `if (Convert.ToBoolean(intLimiter = 1))` supposed to do? Did you mean `if (intLimiter == 1)`?

Comment: @Henrik Yeah, that seems to do it. Not the first time today that == has gotten the best of me. Ah well! Thanks to all, I think this part of my project works now.

Answer (score 1):

As of what I understand from your question, you want to separate the if statements to work all at the same time...
What you can do is create new 'Threads' for each statement which would make you able to run all of then at once...

For thread, make sure you include the namespace System.Threading.

```
using System.Threading;
```

Now what you should do with your code:

```
...

if (DateTime.Now.Hour == intAlarmHour && DateTime.Now.Minute == intAlarmMinute)
{


    if (radTG.Checked == true)
    {
        Thread radTG = new Thread(radTGChecked);
        radTG.Start();
    }
    ...
}

...

public void radTGChecked() {
    SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Celldweller);
    sound.PlaySync();
}
```

Do this to all the if statements following, and they will all run together, each on a thread...
Forgive me if that was not the answer of your question, but the title corresponding to the content does seem a little blurry to me...
But if it did, [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)'s an article that will help you understand Multi-Threading.